# Onclicking android app icon url should open

Tags: android, onclick

I am new Developer in android. I want to create one simple app in which i will click on icon than it should open my website in browser.

Can someone suggest me what i should do

Comment: use a webview to load ur url. searching on stackoverflow u will find some solutions regarding the same.

Comment: @Rahil2952 can you give me any tutorial link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create android project
add **WebView** in main layout
attach to webview in code, then load url

Answer (score 0):

Use WebView and refer [link for webview](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        Intent open = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
        startActivity(open);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```